# Writing About A Personal Experience, Without Any

Tags: non-fiction, planning

I don't want to get into the details of everything for the sake of time. An upcoming personal essay requires me to talk about how I feel about nature and how I feel as if it has defined me. This would be fine, yet, I'm required to also use an **actual experience** in my life that includes nature so I'm not just saying general ideas about my relationship with the outside world. This is where my problem comes in. I'm not an outside person, and I don't enjoy the outside world either. I don't know how to swim or ride a bike, because I didn't spend any moment of my childhood outside. Are there any general experiences I could use while being entirely generic, that is still helpful?
While I sat here writing this, *maybe* I could write about how nature is very unknown to me.

Comment: One of the most hated parts of school - write something personal for all the jerk kids in the class to read.  "Nope.  None of your business."  Make something up, or write something else entirely.

Comment: Had something similar... subject involved a very liberal concept while i myself am conservative orientated... never have i lied so much in a document.  I just wrote the opposite of what i actually believed and the teacher loved it...

Comment: "Nature" is not necessarily out in the woods or hiking the Grand Canyon. It's basically anything that isn't made by humans. A squirrel, for example. A sunset.  Or your desire for breakfast, which is part of your nature.

Answer (score 2):

> An upcoming personal essay requires me to talk about how I feel about nature and how I feel as if it has defined me.

It doesn't have to be positive!

How do you feel about nature? It alienates you.

How does nature define you? By it's absence in your life. Unlike most people, you were raised isolated from nature, indoors. You were not taught to navigate natural environments, swimming, hiking, climbing, riding bikes, playing in trees or fields.

Nature for you is "outside", not just literally but outside your experience, the unknown and uncontrolled, possibly dangerous, and a place you do not wish to be.

you define yourself by staying away from nature.

Answer (score 1):

Not having experienced something many other people have experienced is also an experience. Angles you could go for:

- Your personal story about why you never made these experiences
- Your feelings when other people tell you about their experiences
- Reasons why you want or don't want to make those experiences and what you would expect from them
- How that makes you feel